# C++ ofstream Huge Text File

Tags: c++, arrays, stream, fstream, ofstream

So, here's my code for a simple part of a class:

```
void ArrayToTextFile::textfiller(string *givenpointer){
    cout<< "Recieved array pointer address" << givenpointer << endl;
    const char * constantcharversion = path.c_str();
    ofstream filler(constantcharversion);

    int i = 0;
    //string delims = (string)delim;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(*givenpointer); i++) {
        filler << *givenpointer << delim;
        givenpointer = givenpointer + 1;
    }
    filler.close();
}
```

The pointer points the first element in an array of strings.

`delim` is a ';'

This is my main class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ArrayToTextFile.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color 1A");

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    string kinch[3] = {"a", "second el", "third"};
    ArrayToTextFile newone("C:/haha.txt", ';');
    string *pointy = &kinch[0];

    newone.textfiller(pointy);
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever the program runs, I can never make it to the return statement. In fact I have to click the exit button on the console window. When I look at the text file created it's huge:

[image: Look here]

What is my problem? How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you expect `sizeof(*givenpointer)` to be returning?  Hint - it's not the number of strings in your array.

Comment: use givenpointer->size() instead of sizeof(*givenpointer).

Comment: Oh, I see given pointer will return the size of one element. How can I find the size of the array then?

Comment: @Cygwinnian: You can't. Either use `std::vector<...>` or give the number of elements as additional argument.

Comment: @Cygwinnian, you can't, without passing it in or using a more C++-ey collection type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the number of elements in the array. `sizeof` will only give you a size in bytes, which is rarely useful. In order to get the size of an array, you can use `(sizeof array)/(sizeof array[0])`, but inside the function you only have a pointer, not an array, and this will give you different results.